# How do I call my child on Google Hangouts on iOS

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-hangouts, google-family-link

I would like to talk to my child in Google Hangouts.

I created an account for my child and I linked it in a family group, but apparently it is not possible to use family link accounts in Hangouts on iOS.

I then tried to remove the child account from the family group and change the age, but I cannot find any functionality to remove the child from family group.

I cannot delete the account and re-create it again because the name will be gone.

How can this be done without losing the name on the Gmail account?

Comment: Did you try web Hangouts - https://hangouts.google.com/ ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using an iOS app, not web application as it's defined in [help/on-topic]. This might be on-topic in [apple.se]

Comment: @Rubén: There's also a Google Family Link web application.  [(Source.)](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/41482/how-to-manage-your-childs-google-family-link-settings-using-a-web-browser#41483)  Therefore, I wonder if you could please reopen this question?

Comment: @tealhillsupportsMonica This question isn't about using Google Familiy Link web app, it's about using mobile apps on iOS. Have you already look at [apple.se] for questions like this?